# In diagrams.net, create "connector with symbol" with custom shape

Tags: draw.io, diagrams.net

Pretty recently, in the "General" section of shapes, the "connector with symbol" was added.

I was able to replace the email symbol with built-in shapes by editing the "Style" of the shape and setting `shape=message` to `shape=cloud`, for instance. But custom shapes (shapes in the Scratchpad) can't be referenced this way.

Now, how do I replace the pre-defined email symbol in the connector with a **custom** shape?

Example:

[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How and where did you create a custom shape? E.g if you take a custom shape described here:https://www.diagrams.net/doc/faq/custom-shapes, add it to canvas, press Ctrl+e to see the code, copy all shape related lines after "shape=" and paste it into e.g message shape, you should see message shape replaced with custom one.

Comment: I just had to use the plain shape name ("mxgraph.signs.safety.no"), replace it with the "message", which is predefined for the "connection with shape" and then select the shape afterwards and style it as I want (in my case it was sketch and color red). Thanks for the hint!